# How to prevent npm from creating the ~/.npm directory when I run "npm install"?

Tags: docker, npm

I have a Vue.js project that I am attempting build in Docker using the `node:latest` container. Here are the relevant lines in my `Makefile` that installs the packages the project requires:

```
CWD = $(shell pwd)
UID = $(shell id -u)
GID = $(shell id -g)

# ...

sometarget:
    docker run \
        --rm \
        -e HOME=/home/node \
        -u ${UID}:${GID} \
        -v ${CWD}:/usr/src/app \
        -w /usr/src/ui \
        node:latest \
        npm install
```

Note: by overriding user and group IDs, I am able to ensure that the files created by `npm install` have the correct ownership, allowing the current user to run `make clean` afterwards.

The `npm install` invocation attempts to create `~/.npm`. However, if the current user and group ID do not match those of the `node` user in the container, I end up with an error:

```
npm ERR! path /home/node/.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/node/.npm'
```

I'd like to have `npm` skip the creation of `/home/node/.npm` entirely, if possible. Is there a flag that prevents the creation of this directory? The container is ephemeral, so there is no value in preserving the contents of the directory.

Comment: As an alternative, what about running the command as the user “node”?

Comment: @zero298 if I run the command as `node` then the files created by the command will have a different user / group ID on the host and the host user won't be able to write / delete them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11338):

> The short answer is no, it's not possible to bypass the CLI's cache.

Basically, `npm` install is essentially:

1. populate the cache with the requested packages
2. extract from the cache

Given that, your options likely change to:

1. (as the `node` user) `npm install && npm cache clean`
2. `chown -R "$UID:$GID" node_modules`

Another option is to mount a temp directory as the user (assume TMP_DIR was made using `mktmp -d` or some sort):

```
    -v $TMP_DIR:/home/node \
    -e HOME=/home/node \
```

The mounted directory will exist and will be owned by the user so it'll be writable.

Yet another option (since you don't actually care about the cache directory at all) is to set `HOME` to the temporary directory (which has the sticky bit set so it'll be writable by anyone:

```
    -e HOME=/tmp \
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I especially like the last option (using `/tmp`) - I think I'll go that route.